# Easier way to find matching array from a lot of arrays

Tags: java, array

I have the following arrays which save the MAC-adresses of a lot of bluetooth beacons and their positions in a building:

```java
private static final String[][] MAC_ADDRESSES_A_BLUETOOTH = {{"B09122F5D126", "210.105"}, {"B09122F5F26B", "136.121"}, {"B09122F5F619", "181.172"}};
...
private static final String[][] MAC_ADDRESSES_Q_BLUETOOTH = {{"B09122F5D124", "210.105"}, {"B09122F5F26Z", "136.121"}, {"B09122F5F61Q", "181.172"}};
```

Then I'm looking for the matching triple based on a current triple:

```java
private String[][] compareArrays(String[] beacon) {
        if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_A_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_A_BLUETOOTH;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_B_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_B_BLUETOOTH;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_C_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_C_BLUETOOTH;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_D_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_D_BLUETOOTH;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_F_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_F_BLUETOOTH;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_G_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_G_BLUETOOTH;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_H_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_H_BLUETOOTH;
        } else if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(MAC_ADDRESSES_I_BLUETOOTH))) {
            return MAC_ADDRESSES_I_BLUETOOTH;
        } ...
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

This code looks horrible and it bugs me. Is there an easier way to do this without having to write 16 `if` statements? `getFirstArray` returns all first values from a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability, use an Object instead of a 2d array.

E.G:

```
public class BluetoothMacAddress {
    private String macAddress;
    private float positionInBuilding;
}
```

Use `java.util.List`, then you can have a list of lists:

```
private sttaic final List<MacAddress> MAC_ADDRESSES_A_BLUETOOTH = Arrays.asList(
    new BluetoothMacAddress("B09122F5D126", "210.105"),  
    new BluetoothMacAddress("B09122F5F26B", "136.121"), 
    new BluetoothMacAddress("B09122F5F619", "181.172"));

private static final List<List<MAC_ADDRESSES>> MAC_ADDRESSES = Arrays.asList(
    MAC_ADDRESSES_A_BLUETOOTH,
    MAC_ADDRESSES_B_BLUETOOTH 
    ...
);
```

Your new method would then look something like this:

```
private MacAddress compareArrays(String[] beacon) {
    for (List<MacAddress> macAddresses : MAC_ADDRESSES ) {
        if (Arrays.equals(beacon, getFirstArray(macAddresses))) {
            return macAddresses;
        }
    }
    // not found
    return null;
}
```

You'd have to change the `beacon` parameter to be a `MacAddress` too, or convert the `MacAddress` to a `String[]` (or visa-versa).

Comment: Used your solution, needed to change a lot in my other code, but looks cleaner in the end.